# expand body or wrapper height with an absolute div inside

Tags: html, css, wordpress, tabs, height

I'm working on a website on wordpress.

I have a wrapper with header and entry inside of it.

my Body height is set to height: 100%;
Wrapper is set to height: 100% and min-height: 100%.

The height of my page expand depending of the content of my entry, that works perfectly on most of pages.

but on some pages, I've included Pure CSS Tabs, which are set to position:absolute to work.
I used this example : http://www.onextrapixel.com/2013/07/31/creating-content-tabs-with-pure-css/

on pages including those tabs my content doesn't expand anymore, I can not use position:relative for the tabs...

Is there a way of expending the body height depending of my tab contact height ?
maybe using Js ?
can anybody help me ?

here is my css :

```
html,body{
width: 100%;
max-width: 1220px;
font-family: 'andale';
font-size:14px;
line-height: 20px;
color: black;
text-transform: none;
background-color: #4C4C4C;
letter-spacing: 2px;height: 97%;}

#wrapper{
background-color: white;
height: auto !important; /* ie6 ignores !important, so this will be overridden below */     min-height: 100%; /* ie6 ignores min-height completely */     
margin-left: 20px;
margin-top: 20px;
padding-top: 20px;
height: 100%;}

.entry{
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;}

#header{
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 20px;
width: 100%;
color: #FF5000;
text-decoration: none}

.menu-menu-container{clear: both;padding-top: 5px;}
#menu-menu {list-style:none;}
.menu-item {float:left;}
#menu-menu li:after{content:"\00a0|";}
#menu-menu li:before{content:"\00a0";}
#menu-menu li:first-child:before{content:"";}
#menu-menu li:last-child:after{content:"";}
#menu-menu li.current_page_item a { color:#FF5000;text-decoration: line-through }
#menu-menu li.current-page-ancestor a { color:#FF5000;text-decoration: line-through }

.tabs input[type=radio] {
position: absolute;
top: -9999px;
left: -9999px;
}
.tabs {
list-style: none;
position: relative;}

.tabs li{
float: left;}

.tabs li:after{
content:"|\00a0";}
.tabs li:last-child:after{
content:"";}
.tabs label:hover {
color:#FF5000;
text-decoration: line-through}
[id^=tab]:checked + label {
color:#FF5000;
text-decoration: line-through}
[id^=tab]:checked ~ [id^=tab-content] {display: block;}
.tab-content{
z-index: 2;
display: none;
text-align: left;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
position: absolute;}
```

here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MPhnP/

anyone can help me with this ? is it possible using the css tabs I'm using ?
thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score -1):

Wow, I remember battling with this exact problem a couple of months ago, I was even using those exact same tabs you linked.

The thing with absolute positioning is that you are positioning the elements outside of the normal flow of the webpage - any div with position absolute will not contribute to the page flow.

This leaves you with 2 options:

Manually set the height of the tab group. For example:

```
    .tabs {
        height: 450px;
     }
```

I don't like this solution as it means you can't have a dynamic height for each tab - all tabs will be the same height. If your first tab had only a few lines of text and your 2nd one had many paragraphs, the whole thing would just look weird, or you would have a large gap under the tab group.

So what are your other options? Ditch pure CSS tabs and use jQuery. Honestly, I spent hours and hours researching pure CSS tabs trying to find/create some that were practical and functional, and I concluded it just isn't feasible. Pure CSS tabs are just gimmicks and a brilliant example of the power of CSS, but I do not believe they have any practical use in a production environment.

EDIT: It just occurred to me you probably CAN use JS to get your tabs to work how you want, but if you're going to go down that route, why not just use JS tabs?